# End time must be greater than start time by at least one multiple of the granularity type

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm doing a Linkeidn Api call to ge the statistics of a posts. I'm calling the following endpoint

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics with some queryParams
timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY
timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1678802465
timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1715695265

But I'm getting an error of  **End time must be greater than start time by at least one multiple of the granularity type**

I've checked the dates with a epoch converter and they seem to be right, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts:

1. Your end time is equivalent to May 14, 2024. This seems wrong; the latest end time should be is the current time.
2. Your time range spans more than 12 months. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http):

> The organizationalEntityShareStatistics endpoint returns share data only within the past 12 months, using a rolling 12-month window.

Answer (score 0):

Your time range start and end values are in seconds. The [Share statistics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http#retrieve-lifetime-share-statistics) specifies that the values should be in milliseconds.

timeIntervals.timeRange.start

> Inclusive starting timestamp of when the query should begin (milliseconds since epoch)....

You can simply multiply your start and end values by a 1000 to make it work.